# scatter chart formula

Tags: php, math, charts

I am trying to create a scatter chart on my web page with CSS and few dots images. I have created the design successfully, but now I can't figure out how a scatter chart  actually works.  Can anyone provide me any idea how I can arrange them?  My chart width is 968 and height 432.
like this chart

http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=s&chd=t:12,16,16,24,26,28,41,51,66,68,13,45,81|16,14,22,34,22,31,31,48,71,64,15,38,84&chs=250x100&chl=Hello|World

i cannot use this but i want to know how it works

Thanks for any help.

```
<?php
$w = 968; $h = 432;
$xmin = 0; $xmax = 968;
$ymin = 10; $ymax = 100;
$x = 10; $y = 10;
$xc = 20;
$yc = 20;
$r = (20)/ 2;
 $xc = $w * (($x - $xmin)/($xmax - $xmin)) - $r . "<br>";
$yc = $h * (($ymax - $y)/($ymax - $ymin)) -$r;
$tr ='';
$data = array("120|90","345|456","45|66","45|45");
foreach($data as $value){
    $new =  explode("|",$value);
    $tr .='<a href="#" style="top:'.$new[0].'px; left:'.$new[1].'px;" class="dot"></a>';
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>

    <style type="text/css">
#most_engaged_graph{
width:968px;
height:432px;
background-color:#CCCCCC;
}
a.dot {
 height:20px;
 width:20px;
 position:absolute;
 background-color:#0033FF;
}
</style>  
</head>
<body>
<div id="most_engaged_graph"> 
<?=$tr?>   
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well your dot pitch is `20px` square, and you need to position them on the graph with the bottom left corner as the origin `(0,0)`.

You need to know the scale of the axis, which you have not stated.  Decide how many pixels per distance upon your axis.

Then you need to convert the position you desire of each point `P(x,y)`, to a position on the screen.  You want the centre pixel of your `.dot` to be at that location.

As the screen coordinate run from top-left, not bottom-left, you will need to reverse the vertical pixels, so maximum is zero, and zero (or full negative) is the height of the graph, plus/minus half the size of your dot in both cases.

Given:

- `W = graph width (px), H = graph height (px)`
- `Xmin = minimum x axis, Xmax = maximum x axis`
- `Ymin = minimum y axis, Ymax = maximum y axis`
- `x = x value on graph (Xmin <= x <= Xmax), y = y value on graph (Ymin <= y <= Ymax)`
- `Xc = x-center of dot, Yc = y-center of dot`
- `r = dot radius = (dot width) / 2`

Then:

- `Xc = W * [(x - Xmin)/(Xmax - Xmin)], Yc = H * [(Ymax - y)/(Ymax - Ymin)]`
- `left = Xc - r, top = Yc - r`

Untested, I think that is right - might need adjustment.  In particular, subtract `2r` from `W` and `H` if you need the dots to appear fully within the area (that applies to the whole of the graph, axis et al).

---

**Example code:**

```
<div id="most_engaged_graph"> 
<?php
$dataPoints = array(
                    array('x' => 5, 'y' => 20),
                    array('x' => 80, 'y' => 50),
                    array('x' => 45, 'y' => 5),
                    array('x' => 68, 'y' => 89),
                    array('x' => 22, 'y' => 43)
              );

foreach ($dataPoints as $cPoint) {
    // Assuming $w, $h, $xmin, $ymin, $xmax, $ymax, $r are defined above
    $xc = $w * (($cPoint['x'] - $xmin) / ($xmax - $xmin));
    $yc = $h * (($ymax - $cPoint['y']) / ($ymax - $ymin));

    $cLeft = $xc - $r;
    $cTop  = $yc - $r;
?>
    <a href="#" style="top: <?php echo $cTop; ?>px; left: <?php echo $cLeft; ?>px;" class="dot"></a>
<?php
}
?>
</div>
```

**jQuery version Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/75Mz5/1/**

Comment: i edit the code for to more understands i try working with your idea but i think i did it totaly in wrong way can you have me one simple working example many thanks for the help

Comment: @livetolearn: Looking at your code, you have the calculations right.  But are not using them, you have 3 hand positioned "dots" in the HTML.  You need to use the final values for `top` and `left`, I don't know why you have `<br>` on the end of `Xc` either.  Also, I made a slight error using `Xc` and `Yc` twice. I will correct that now.

Comment: @livetolearn: Additionally, you might not have the right idea about `Xmin, Xmax, Ymin, Ymax`, they are the graph axis limits (scales), not the pixels on your screen.

Comment: i dont know how do i use the php code into html code should i create a array of numbers and run a loop and display all from the loop but i dont know to use this code i made from you idea

Comment: @livetolearn: Yes, that sounds right, a little loop for all the points.  I'll make an example on my answer.

Comment: working prfetly but when i give a large value it go so far on right or in bottom how can i just let them set on stage only

Comment: ok i got what is xmin or xmax is but what is •Xc = x-center of dot, Yc = y-center of dot can you explain

Comment: The initial mention of `Xc` and `Yc` was just telling you what they are for the, centre point of the "dot".  They are not intended as things you define.  When calculating the position on the graph, it is the centre of the dot you want to position.  But in CSS, you need to position the top-left, hence the subtraction of `r`.

Comment: The values of the dots *must* be within the axis scales, `xmin <= x <= xmax, ymin <= y <= ymax`.

Comment: can you edit the code so i can get a clear idea of it thanks sp much for the help i really learned a lot

Comment: @livetolearn: Right, wrote a jQuery demo, so you can see the code and the graph working at the same time, enter coordinates in the box at the top and hit add: **http://jsfiddle.net/75Mz5/1/**

Comment: thanks but same problm when i enter a big value like 656 or 65456 then page get so big i am just trying to be on the chart not outside of it

Comment: @livetolearn: You have to make sure the graph axis can cope with the range of values you are going to give it.  It says on the demo, the range is set as 0 to 100, no values outside are allowed.  If you want values that high xmax/ymax need to be higher.

Comment: got it manyyyyyyyyyy thanks i think now i know how charts work finaly

Answer (score 1):

Well, there are two parts really. First you have to establish a scale. I typically do slightly more than the extremes. So if you take the top, right, left, and bottom-most value, add/subtract a little or to make it fit a power of ten. Then you have a scale. From here, you can use math to decide where each dot goes. It doesn't simply go at the value location, you have to scale it to fit the chart.

So, let's say you have a scale of 1000 by 1000. But your chart is only 100 by 100. In this case, each pixel will count for 10. So the value 40,40 will be located at 4,4 on your plot.

You also need to bear in mind the existence of negative numbers. If the plot was -500 to 500 and not 0 to 1000, you would need to move 4,4 to 54,54 to place them in the correct location.

Hopefully this helps you figure the rest out.

Comment: thanks for your anwser can you write a small formula for in any lang that i can understand easily that will be helpfull

Comment: Unfortunately no. It will depend pretty heavily on how you end up doing it and what you want to support. But the above looks something like. Offset = (value + |negative boundary|) / (range / window_size) Assuming an origin of bottom left, not top left as you are doing.